# Select max value for group by column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, rank

I have a table `Question` with columns

```
QuestionId, Question, AnswerId, Answer, AnsVotes(integer), AnsDate(Date)
```

One `QuestionId` can have multiple `AnswerId`'s therefore multiple entries. `AnswerId` is unique

How can I filter the records to get `QuestionId`'s with `AnswerId`'s having maximum `AnsVotes`? And if `Ansvotes` is the same for multiple entries, then get the row with latest `AnsDate` (which is a date column).

Comment: search for "having" in a sql query,this allows filtering on aggregated values. you also need to try to solve your problem. what have you tired?

Comment: Looks like bad design to me: you're duplicating questions data for every possible answer. You should move the answers to another table and add a foreign key referring to the question

Comment: If AnswerId is unique, I'd rather call this table `Answer`, not `Question`. Moreover you'd have a question repeated in the table (same ID and hopefully the same text). That's not good. Make this a separate question table instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will separate the table into Question and Answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the top entry without allwing for ties. Use `TOP(1)` for this:

```
select top(1) *
from question
order by ansvotes desc, ansdate desc;
```

Or do you want to get the best answer *per question* instead? Then you'd rank your records with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select *
from
(
  select q.*, row_number() over (partition by questionid 
                                 order by ansvotes desc, ansdate desc) as rn
  from question q
) answers
where rn = 1;
```